# Do you need to be a certified Sitecore developer to download installation files?

Tags: installation, migration

I am trying to migrate the site from 8.2 to 9. In order to upgrade the site, we require the migration files, which you can usually download from the [Sitecore Downloads site](https://dev.sitecore.net/).

If the client has purchased the correct license for Sitecore 9 then is it enough to download the required installation/upgrade files, or do we need developer to be Sitecore certified as well.

Comment: Check following if this can be helpful:
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/what-to-do-if-i-cant-download-packages-from-sitecore

Answer (score 3):

As of today (December 12, 2020) there has been a change in how you can access downloads for Sitecore software. You no longer need the proper license or certification or even to login to download the software. You will still need a license to run the software, though.

From the [announcement](https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/sitecore-downloads-are-now-global) that I posted:

> Sitecore has placed all downloads from dev.sitecore.net onto a global CDN to provide faster download times and availability to wherever you find yourself in the world!
> [...]
>
> This also comes with another welcome change that has been asked for by the community for a long time: **no more account logins for downloads!**
>
> This aligns with the existing public availability of Sitecore NuGet packages and the new Sitecore Docker Image Repository.
>
> Sitecore software is now available to download for everybody, anywhere in the world, no restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to login using the certified Sitecore developer's account in-order to download any files from https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/

Client can only purchase the license compatible for running Sitecore 9 instance.

Comment: This was a correct answer at the time. As of today, this answer no longer applies as Sitecore has moved the downloads to a CDN and login is no longer required to download.