# What to do if I can't download packages from Sitecore?

Tags: installation

I am a Sitecore certified developer but when I go to https://dev.sitecore.net/ and I am logged in I still cannot download the packages.

What can I do in this case?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Dec 14, 2020 **you do not need to be certified and logged in to be able to download the packages** from https://dev.sitecore.net/

More details on this: https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/technical-marketing/posts/sitecore-downloads-are-now-global

---

### If you still have issues use the contact information below to find help:

If you work for a partner and you ***have access*** to the Partner portal please contact Sitecore using this form:
https://partners.sitecore.com/s/contactsupport

If you work for a partner and you ***don't have access*** to the Partner portal please contact Sitecore using this form:
https://partners.sitecore.com/s/get-help

In every other case please contact Sitecore using this form:
https://www.sitecore.com/company/contact-us

If you are a Sitecore MVP you get a license from Sitecore and you can download the packages. If you have any issues then please contact the Sitecore MVP team.

Comment: So you now NEED to be associated with a partner, just being certified is not enough? What about those working for end clients directly or freelancers who are not associated to a partner?

Comment: The answer is wrong - I have just downloaded the XP single packages just to test this and it works ok. No partner.

Comment: If the partner requirement will be a fixture for dev.sitecore.net and packages, customers like me will have to find alternatives to the Sitecore ecosystem. I would really think hard about that partner requirement and certainly include established customer teams as well.

Comment: Have the rules changed? Does Sitecore want all freelancers to change technology?

Comment: I am an independent consultant contracted on a temporal basis by clients who need a specific area to be done. Does that mean I won't have access in the future?

Comment: If anyone (certified developer) working for client not with Service Implementation Partner then they can't download required Sitecore Softwares? If yes, then how Client Team will proceed with Development 

Comment: Sorry I forgot customers but added now. And this is not a statement about who gets access but about what to do if you don't have it and you think you should. If you already have access it will not change.

Comment: To make clear of the real intent of the question I rephrased it and also updated the answer.